# Why do I get NameError with `bundle exec ruby [file]` given that the necessary gem is in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I'm doing some messing around to try to understand better how bundler works. I have just three files in my working directory:

`Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  test.rb`

All the Gemfile has is `gem "slop"` and `test.rb` looks like this:

`puts Slop.parse`

When I run `bundle exec test.rb` I get a `NameError` due to not having a `require` statement:

```
[ec2-user@xx my_app]$ bundle exec ruby test.rb
test.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Slop (NameError)
```

But if I run `bundle console`, Bundler loads the gem correctly and I can run `Slop.parse` from the console without having to explicitly type `require "slop"`:

```
[ec2-user@xx my_app]$ bundle console
irb(main):001:0> Slop.parse
=> #<Slop::Result:0x00000001339838...
```

So what am I missing? I was under the impression that since I don't have `require: false` in my `Gemfile`, `Slop` should be loaded when I run `bundle exec ruby test.rb` and I shouldn't need to put the `require "slop"` line in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to config bundler to require all gems on your `Gemfile` like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)
```

Check the docs at http://bundler.io/v1.12/bundler_setup.html

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression that since I don't have `require: false` in
>   my Gemfile, Slop should be loaded when I run bundle exec ruby test.rb
>   and I shouldn't need to put the require "slop" line in the file.

The [bundler docs](http://bundler.io) say:

> Specify your dependencies in a Gemfile in your project's root:
>
> ```
> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> gem 'nokogiri'   #<======HERE
> ```

---

> Inside your app, load up the bundled environment:
>
> ```
> require 'rubygems' 
> require 'bundler/setup'
>
> # require your gems as usual 
> require 'nokogiri'   #<========AND HERE
> ```

---

As for this:

> I was under the impression that since I don't have `require: false` in
>   my Gemfile, Slop should be loaded when I run bundle exec ruby test.rb
>   and I shouldn't need to put the require "slop" line in the file.

The bundler docs are horrible on this point.  As far as I can tell, `:require => false` is a Rails specific thing, which is used to decrease load times on project startup.  ***In a rails app***, specifying `require: false` means that the gem won't be loaded until you manually require the gem.  If you don't specify `:require => false`, then the gem will be loaded automatically--however that is because rails code is written to do that automatic loading.  Your app has no code that performs a similar function.

**Edit:** Made a mistake while testing.  So here's the way it works: ***In a non rails app***, e.g. in your test.rb, if you want to automatically require all the gems specified in your Gemfile, you need to write:

```
Bundler.require :default
```

The [Bundler docs](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) mention that in the fine print here:

> Specify `:require => false` to prevent bundler from requiring the gem,
>   but still install it and maintain dependencies.
>
> ```
> gem 'rspec', :require => false
> gem 'sqlite3'
> ```
>
> ***In order to require gems in your Gemfile, you will need to call `Bundler.require` in your application.***

I'm not sure why that requirement was only mentioned in conjunction with `require: false` instead of being stated at the outset.

And, in your Gemfile if you specify:

```
gem 'slop', :require => false
```

(as well as `Bundler.require :default` in test.rb), then you also have to explicitly require the slop gem in test.rb:

```
 require 'slop'
```

In other words, `Bundler.require :default` automatically requires all the gems in your Gemfile except the gems marked with `require: false`.  For gems marked with `require: false`, you have to manually write `require 'gem_name'` in your app.

Therefore, neydroid posted the correct solution.

---

`*` In your Gemfile, you can nest gems in groups, which affects how Bundler.require() works.  See the [Bundler docs on groups](http://bundler.io/groups.html).

Comment: No idea why this was originally downvoted but I've given +1 and appreciate the thoroughness

Answer (score -2):

You should add the require "slop" inside your test.rb